# How to add an item from one listview to another listview on click in android example needed

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

Could someone recommend a good example of how to add an item from my listview to another listview after i click the item? i am having trouble with this and would like an example which i can follow from start to finish. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your two listview use the same adapter (ie the same data type) you can use something like this :

```
listView1.setOnItemClickListener(this);

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    datasListView2.add(valuesListView1.get(position));
    listView2.notifyDataSetChange();
}
```

Where dataListView1 and dataListView1 are your values arrays.

Comment: Thanks, i figured it out based on the above.